React project from Vite to Webpack. Does not see css modules
There's a React project with Vite + TypeScript bundler, I'm in the process of migrating the project to Webpack. Everything seems fine except for an issue with CSS modules. It's as if they're not being recognized, resulting in an error during the build process. For example:
in ./src/shared/UI/Button/Button.tsx 18:29-34
export 'default' (imported as 's') was not found in './Button.module.scss' (possible exports: btn, color_accent, color_light, container, disabled, root)

When launching the project, for example, the error looks like this:
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapper')

I import styles like this: import styles from './RelatedItems.module.scss';
webpack.config:
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
// import TsCheckerPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const getSettingsForStyles = (withModules = false) => {
  return [
    isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
    !withModules
      ? 'css-loader'
      : {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              localIdentName: !isProd ? '[path][name]__[local]' : '[hash:base64]',
            },
          },
        },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        postcssOptions: {
          plugins: ['autoprefixer'],
        },
      },
    },
    'sass-loader',
  ];
};

export default {
  entry: path.resolve(srcPath, 'main.tsx'),
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  target: !isProd ? 'web' : 'browserslist',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.s?css$/,
        use: getSettingsForStyles(),
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.s?css$/,
        use: getSettingsForStyles(true),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
    !isProd && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    isProd &&
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
      }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.jsx', '.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      '@pages': path.join(srcPath, 'pages'),
      '@features': path.join(srcPath, 'features'),
      '@widgets': path.join(srcPath, 'widgets'),
      '@shared': path.join(srcPath, 'shared'),
      '@entities': path.join(srcPath, 'entities'),
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
};

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@widgets/*": ["widgets/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["entities/*"],
      "@features/*": ["features/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    },

    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"],
  "include": ["src", "main.tsx", "custom.d.ts", "declaration.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["tsconfig.json"]
}

declaration.d.ts:
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

custom.d.ts:
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

babel.config:
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

  return {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && 'react-refresh/babel'].filter(Boolean),
  };
};

I tried this as well, but still got an error: import * as styles from './RelatedItems.module.scss';
